# How to use the input as domain/<input> instead of domain/?get=<input> in PHP?

Tags: php, parameters

I want to get the value of the VARIABLE_PARAMETER, if someone opens the following link: www.example.com/VARIABLE_PARAMETER in PHP instead of making GET request's to make a dynamic webpage using PHP. Kindly explain the procedure, if possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a mod_rewrite rule in a .htaccess file.

Create a htaccess file with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\/]+)$ index.php?url=$1
```

When you request the page with domain/test (is the same as domain/index.php?url=test), you can access it in the $_GET variable ($_GET["url"]).

Comment: You might want to explain how.

Comment: Note: the regex in the RewriteRule only allows characters, numbers and hyphons in this example

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to make a browser request a URL in that format from a form submission naturally. You have to apply program logic to it.

You've tagged this PHP so a server side solution would be to examine the requested URL with that and then issue a redirect.

```
<?php
    # form_action.php
    if (isset($_GET['get'])) {
        sanity_check_value_of($_GET['get']);
        header("Location: http://www.example.com/" . urlencode($_GET['get']);
        exit;
    }
```

You could also achieve this with a URL rewriting tool such as [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) or [URL rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

It is also possible to handle this client side using JavaScript (by capturing the submit event on the form, preventing the default behaviour, generating the new URL and assigning it to `location`) but the speed benefits over doing it server side probably aren't enough to justify the extra work (and you [shouldn't do it without the server side alternative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)).

Answer (score -1):

Use Post request method rather than Get request method. For tutorial please refer  [W3schoolsTutorial Form Handling](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

Comment: Using a POST request wouldn't work, that would make the `<input>` portion entirely hidden instead of moving it from the query string to the path.